# XCode missing tvOs simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, tvos

I'm trying to build a multiplatform game using XCode, but I can only deploy to iOS device simulators. I added the apple tv simulator, but it doesn't appear as a run destination. Any advice?

Comment: You selected `tvOS` as your baseSDK and `Apple TV` for the Targeted Device Family, right?

Comment: I just did that, it was my first multiplatform app and I didn't know that I had to do that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. When in doubt, create a new project using Xcode and select the defaults you need - ie. tvOS. I do that frequently when extending existing apps towards other platforms that Apple supports. That way I see the boilerplate needed for the specific platform and copy :).